KMM Project Stuck on Installing in iOS Simulator and Causes Device Lag/Restart
I'm facing a very strange issue with my Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) project. When I attempt to install the app on the iOS simulator, Xcode gets stuck on the installation process and doesn't actually complete it unless I restart the simulator, then it works normally.
Additionally, when I try to install the app on a physical device, the device itself experiences significant lag and even restarts. Deleting the app from the device forces the iOS system to restart, which feels like I'm deploying a virus! 
Steps I've Taken:
I ensured that both Xcode and my iOS simulator are updated to the latest versions.
Cleared the derived data in Xcode to see if it improves the installation process.
Tried reinstalling the app multiple times and switching between different simulator configurations.
Environment:
Kotlin Version: 1.9.23
Xcode Version: 15.4
macOS Version: 14.6.1 Apple M1
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any suggestions on how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated!
I attempted to install my KMM project on both the iOS simulator and a physical device. I followed standard procedures in Xcode, including building the project and deploying it directly to the simulator. Additionally, I checked for updates to Xcode and ensured my Kotlin and KMM configurations were up to date.
Tried checking that if a depencendy might be causing all these issues but couldn't identifiy that

The issue turned out to be quite simple yet strange: I had set the app icon as a JPEG file. Once I removed the JPEG icon and reset it to the original PNG format, the problem was resolved.

It looks like Xcode issue
